# What is the return type of clean_formField of manytomany field in django? Can I return list from the function

Tags: python, django

I changed manytomany field to token field with the help of bootstrap tag input javascript plugin. Then I am getting comma (,) separates primary keys as input. After splitting from delimiter comma (,) I got the instance of the exact object. Now how to add those objects to the manytomany field. I tried returning list but it didn't work.

Here is my form class

```
class EventRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    participants = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off', 'data-role':'tagsinput'}),required=True)

    class Meta:
        model=EventRegistration
        fields=['event', 'participants', 'teamName', 'feePaid']

    def clean_feePaid(self):
        feepaid=self.cleaned_data.get('feePaid')
        if not feepaid:
            raise ValidationError('Please pay the fee First :)')
        return feepaid

    def clean_participants(self):
        participants_data = self.cleaned_data.get('participants')
        event = self.cleaned_data.get('event')
        participants =[]

        for pd in participants_data.split(','):
            p = Candidate.objects.get(pk=pd)
            participants.append(p)
        if not (event.minParticipant <= len(participants) <= event.maxParticipant):
            raise ValidationError('Number of Participants exceeded :D')
        return participants

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['event'].empty_label = ''
        # following line needed to refresh widget copy of choice list
        self.fields['event'].widget.choices =self.fields['event'].choices
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one can pass list for m2m field. 
I just missed form.save_m2m().